# Not able to use break point for debugging using VScode extension

Tags: karate

I was using vscode 1.60.0 with karate.robot. My project is based on java+maven.
but not able to put a break point.
Feature files are running fine.

Do I need to download karate.jar & karate.robot.jar for debugging using vs code?
not sure what I am missing?

I am not able to see this :

To setup from a feature file's Codelens

Click Karate: Debug Codelens in any feature file.

Click Karate (debug) option from popup.

Click Add Configurations in launch.json to edit configurations if needed.

Click Karate (debug): Gradle to add Gradle debug.

Click Karate (debug): Maven to add Maven debug.

Edit debug configurations as needed.

Answer (score 1):

The instructions are here: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/Karate-Robot-Windows-Install-Guide

If that is not working, maybe the best thing is to ask for support (file an issue) at the [`karate-runner`](https://github.com/kirksl/karate-runner) project, and you may be asked to provide a working sample in case it is a bug.